# Qual é a melhor forma de fazer exponeciação no Python? Duplo asterisco ou math.pow?

Tags: python

Qual é a melhor forma de fazer exponeciação no Python?

Devo usar o operador `**` ou `math.pow`?

Exemplo `math.pow`:

```
> math.pow(3, 4);
#Imprime: 81.0
```

Exemplo com **duplo asterísco**?

```
> 3 ** 4
#Imprime : 81
```

O que devo levar em consideração na hora de usá-las?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Velocidade

O operador `**` normalmente é mais rápido que `math.pow()`. Ele chama [a função nativa `pow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow), que, aliás, aceita um argumento de módulo. Normalmente é melhor para inteiros.

## Segurança de tipos

`math.pow()` sempre devolve um `float`. Neste caso, quando os tipos são `float`, `math.pow()` é mais rápido.

[Retirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y).

Comment: Mas se quissesemos entrar nessa "segurança de tipos" com o número `3` por exemplo, querendo que ele retorne `float`, poderiamos simplesmente fazer 3.0 ** 3, certo?

Comment: Sim, porque se há pelo menos um `float` envolvido na operação, o resultado é um `float` também.